# why the car doesn't rotate with circle gameobject that the car is on to that

Tags: unity, c#

I have an issue with rotating objects with a circle that I create like this:
[image]

I'm going on that but the car doesn't rotate with the circle rotator.

Here is the rotator script that might help because I don't know where is my problem:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int RotateSpeed;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), RotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Also, I'm using wheel collider but this is not the problem.

For the test, I drop a cube on the circle but the cube doesn't rotate

The rotator friction uses the defaults & here are the wheel friction settings:

[image: Wheel Friction]

Comment: Just to be sure, the circle on the ground rotates and you want objects that are on it to rotate with it, correct? How high is the friction of your objects and the rotator?

Comment: @Zibelas I'm Added them Please check them

Comment: Please be mindful of the guidance when selecting tags. Your screenshot shows version 2022.18 - Unityscript was last available on version 2017.2 & was already considered legacy for a while before that.

Comment: @MobinBagheri that is for the car, what about the platform? Usually it would be a physics material.